# angular 16 ng build library fails (ivy full compilation mode)

Tags: angular, angular-material, compilation, ivy

I had my angular application on `version 10`. I updated it to `version 16` and now when i am building my local (angular) libraries, it fails giving this error.

```
"✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode."
```

my angular library's `package.json` is following.

```json
{
  "name": "@my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

If there is something to add (or remove) in angular 16 to build library? I am an Intermediate to angular Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It's very likely your version of node is no longer compatible. See: https://angular.io/guide/versions. `nvm` is a nice tool to use for quickly swapping between node versions as well as installing new ones.

Comment: i thought the same for a while and checked my node version. its node 20 right now. i am familiar with nvm and i have used it before, but i was not able to download nvm in current project. i guess i should probably try to download nvm, and change my node version. that might help. more over, you have any idea why i cant install nvm using npm ? i have done that before, but now, for some unknown reason i am unable to do that

Comment: If that's your full package.json, you're  missing a lot of default packages. Try generating a new angular project and compare the differences.

Comment: this is my package file of an angular library which i am using in my angular project

Comment: OK, that'll be the primary cause - you are missing quiet a few Angular dependencies for a build. There should be more build error info (either before or after the error you posted) that will help guide you. From memory, there's at least a missing dev dependencies of some `@angular-devkit` items

Answer (score 0):

i actually resolved the issue. i deleted node modules, package-lock.json and clean npm cache, deleted builds of my libs, transferred peer dependencies to same as the versions of my main project. then i installed node packages again. build my libs again and that worked for me.